# jqtouch / google maps api v3 issue

Tags: jquery, google-maps, css-selectors, javascript-framework, jqtouch

I'm having a hard time trying to make jQtouch and Google Maps api V3 together. I've tried almost everything. It seems that the only source of information is [here](http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/issues/detail?id=44) I checked every single post. I'm starting with jQuery and css... so there's a lot of stuff I don't understand.

First of all, I'm using jQtouch framework to build a web app with google maps integration, the problem is that whenever I pan the map, strange flickering occurs. It's like jQtouch and the map are trying to fight for a callback.

I'm using the latest revision out there. And have several bugs, regarding transition/animation functionality (since I don't wrap the map and all the element's divs within the #jqt wrapper) and css issues with some styling. Anyone has successfully achieve a functional setup build for this scenario? (google maps api v3 & jqtouch), I think is not necessary to paste you some code (But if you think is necessary please let me know and I'll do it), If you paste me a minimal example with a map (detailing jqtouch version, and modification to the styles/.js files), and some transition back and forth from the map to another div/section/page, you rock.

Thanks a lot in advance.

And please, let me know if this is kind of 'legal' here, I mean, there's too much loose information on the official wiki, and like 13 'solutions' but nothing concrete... I'm just triying to help anyone who step on in this problem in the future.

Comment: Please do paste a code snippet. You can explain all you want, but the code will explain the problem better. :-)

Comment: Sure thing, i'll update the question.

Comment: Just to clarify, how come you don't want to wrap it within `#jqt`? Could you at least post the `div` structure?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with GMaps on the iPhone but I did notice that jQTouch seems to bizarrely flickr when things are panned via `position: absolute` which is probably the most common way to pan things - jQTouch somehow prefers using `margin` to do the panning. I'm really not sure if this helps in any way (since I'm not sure you can change this in GMaps).

Comment: how did you solve the problem? My maps render in safari, but not in the simulator or on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the online wiki isn't up-to-date for the latest trun version.

Did you try to wrap the map inside an iframe? In my experience, it's a good try to do.